# Integral.Darboux sums

Tags: calculus

Suppose the  lower and upper Darboux sums are denoted by $S$ and $s$ and $K_{1}=\sup s$  and $K_{2}=\inf S$.So a function can be integrated if the lower and upper integral coincide. I can't understand if $S-s < \varepsilon$ is true then $K_1=K_2$.In the book it is given that 
$s\leq K_{1}\leq K_{2} \leq S $ and from this it follows $ K_{1}=K_{2}$,can someone elaborate how this is deduced?

Answer (score 0):

If for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a lower sum $s$ and upper sum $S$ such that $S-s <\varepsilon $ then ofcourse $K_1 =K_2 $ because this follows from the inequality $ s\leq K_{1}\leq K_{2} \leq S .$

Comment: All I can see is $0<=K_{2}-K_{1}<S-s<=e $ .Which means that it is bounded but how does it follow it must be 0?

Comment: And since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary small them we must have $K_2 -K_1 =0.$

Comment: Yes by knowing that ,the theorem of the Policeman it follows $ lim K_{2}-K_{1}=0 $ ,so they are equal :)

Comment: Yes, since for example for  all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $0\leq K_2 -K_1 <\frac{1}{n} $

Comment: Why does it not follow from the beginning S=s?